# Problems with interconnected parameters in PowerShell Param block

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm having troubles wrapping my head around the code logic needed to get my Param block functioning as I want in PowerShell 5.1.  A very simplified (but usable for my request) script with the Param block is here and this works exactly as I want:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'All')]

Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$Name,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'All')]
    [Switch]$All,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Individual')]
    [Switch]$P1,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Individual')]
    [Switch]$P2
    
    )

If ($All -Or ($P1.ToBool() + $P2.ToBool() -eq 0)) {
    $All = $True
    $P1 = $True
    $P2 = $True
    }

"`$Name is $Name"
"`$All is $All"
"`$P1 is $P1"
"`$P2 is $P2"
```

The auto-completion of parameters when running this script above works as intended.  If I use the "-All" switch, then -P# are not available.  If I use -P# switche, -All is not available.  If I omit the -Name, then it prompts me to put in a name.  If I use the -All switch, I want all of the individual -P# options to later be set to $True. If I use no switches at all, it prompts me for a Name then sets all options to $True.

The first problem is that when using **DefaultParameterSetName = 'All'** (which I had to do in order to make the script work without any switches on the command line), then the $All variable is NOT actually being set to $True when it is not present on the command line.  I had to make the "If" block in order to overcome that behavior.  This makes the next problem come up because the actual script I'm trying to use this in will have fifteen or more -P# switches.  That will make the "If" test more complex and ugly.

Is there a better way I can do this?  Maybe something in the layout of my Parameter Sets?  I could even eliminate the "-All" switch entirely if there's an easier way to evaluate that none of the -P# switches are used.   Is there an easier way to add up the boolean value of all Parameters named P#?  I've stumbled across the **$MyInvocation** variable and **$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters** seems promising but I'm not sure exactly how to process that either.

***Update after answer found:***
Here is my new, simplified working code sample which I arrived at thanks to all the suggestions here.  The "-All" Switch was unnecessary.  I decided to go with the Get-Variable method here for now due to its simplicity and scalability, but it does require a common prefix on the Switch variables.  The If() block will remain the same no matter how many variables are used.

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]$Name,
    [Alias('Blue')]
    [Switch]$OptionBlue,
    [Alias('Red')]
    [Switch]$OptionRed,
    [Alias('Yellow')]
    [Switch]$OptionYellow
    )

$AllOptions = Get-Variable -Name 'Option*'
If (-Not $AllOptions.Value.Contains($True)) {
    "None of the Option Switches were used, setting all Option Variables to $True"
    ForEach ($Option In $AllOptions) {$Option.Value = $True}
    }

"`$Name:          $Name"
"`$OptionBlue:    $OptionBlue"
"`$OptionRed:     $OptionRed"
"`$OptionYellow:  $OptionYellow"
```

and here's how it works:

```
PS C:\Scripts\PowerShell> .\Test-Params.ps1

cmdlet Test-Params.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Testing
None of the Option Switches were used, setting all Option Variables to True
$Name:          Testing
$OptionBlue:    True
$OptionRed:     True
$OptionYellow:  True
PS C:\Scripts\PowerShell> .\Test-Params.ps1 -Name Testing -OptionRed
$Name:          Testing
$OptionBlue:    False
$OptionRed:     True
$OptionYellow:  False
PS C:\Scripts\PowerShell> .\Test-Params.ps1 -Name Testing -Blue -Yellow
$Name:          Testing
$OptionBlue:    True
$OptionRed:     False
$OptionYellow:  True
PS C:\Scripts\PowerShell> .\Test-Params.ps1 -Yellow -OptionRed

cmdlet Test-Params.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Testing
$Name:          Testing
$OptionBlue:    False
$OptionRed:     True
$OptionYellow:  True
```

***Final Update***

I figured out the way to avoid any issue where the script's switch parameters might match an already existing variable in the scope. Pulling the script's parameters that match the proper prefix/suffix used in the script's parameter names using $MyInvocation and then passing those specific names to Get-Variable avoids the issue.  The switches also work correctly both when they are not present, or if they are explicitly set to $False.  If more switches are needed, simply add them in the Param block with the proper prefix/suffix in the name and an alias for the simpler version.  I think this bit of the code is bulletproof now...

```
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Name,
        [Alias('Blue')]
        [Switch]$OptionBlue,
        [Alias('Red')]
        [Switch]$OptionRed,
        [Alias('Yellow')]
        [Switch]$OptionYellow
        )
        
    $OptionNotAnOption = $True
    
    $OptionSwitches = ForEach ($Option In ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys | Where {$_ -Like "Option*"})) {Get-Variable $Option}
    
    If ($OptionSwitches.Value.IsPresent -NotContains $True) {
        "All options are `$False or not present: Enabling all options"
        ForEach ($Switch In $OptionSwitches) {
            Get-Variable -Name ($Switch.Name) | Set-Variable -Value $True
            }
        }
    
    "`$Name:               $Name"
    "`$OptionBlue:         $OptionBlue"
    "`$OptionRed:          $OptionRed"
    "`$OptionYellow:       $OptionYellow"
    "`$OptionNotAnOption:  $OptionNotAnOption"
```

Comment: Why not put the 3 switchs into one `String` type parameter and use `[ValidateSet('All', 'P1', 'P2')]` as decoration

Comment: ```($All -Or ($P1.ToBool() + $P2.ToBool() -eq 0))``` makes my eye twitch a little bit - try the equivalent ```($All -or (-not $P1 -and -not $P2))``` to express the logic a bit more clearly (imho) :-)

Comment: Technically, your code should work. The issue is when you're adding the 2 bools, you get 2, and not 0. So, you can just do: `if ($All -or ($P1 -and $P2)) { $All = $P1 = $P2 = $true }`

Comment: @mclayton That seems promising as long as it continues to work over a larger set of -P# variables.  I'll give it a try with 5 or 6 in my test script.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I think the ```if``` checks if *none* of the ```$Px``` are specified rather than if *all* are, so ```(-not $P1 -and -not $P2)``` *or* ```-not ($P1 -or $P2)``` - whichever makes your head hurt less :-)

Comment: @mclayton, see, I thought that at first as well but it seems like they want to make `$All` true if both `$Px`'s are specified? Definitely confusing lol @CitizenRon, can you clarify on that part?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I read it as “use the true/false values from the $Pn parameters if any single one is true” otherwise default them all to $true” - the whole “ToBool-eq 0” is only true if both $Pn are false, but I might have misjudged it trying to do truth tables in my head :-).

Comment: @mclayton, referencing the 2nd paragraph after the code he says, "*..then the `$All` variable is **NOT** actually being set to `$True` when it is not present on the command line*" which led me to that conclusion. I'm probably just overthinking it if I'm being honest haha

Comment: Okay, from the command line perspective of running the script, "-All" and "-P#" should be mutually exclusive command line parameters.  Within the script, if I use "-All" then all fifteen+ of the "-P#" variables should be set to $True, whether in the Param block somehow or later in the script.

Comment: @CitizenRon - do you specifically want to keep the ```-All``` parameter? In my answer below all $Pn parameters default to $true if you specify *none* of them (see example calls)

Comment: I'm thinking of putting kind of a prefix on the "-P#" variables and then in the script I can grab the collection of them using Get-Variable -Name "Prefix*".  They're not actually named "-P#" in the actual script so I need to figure out how to do that while keeping them with usable names.

Comment: It definitely seems to make sense to drop the -All switch in this case and just accept that as the logical default.

Comment: An important problem with using my "Get-Variable" method appears when there's already a variable that matches the pattern used by the script.  It shouldn't happen in practice, but I still may have to rethink this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#psboundparameters) "automatic variable" to access the parameters specified in the call to the script / function and alter the function's behaviour accordingly.

For example:

```
function Invoke-MyFunction
{
    param
    (
        [string] $Name,
        [switch] $P1,
        [switch] $P2
    )

    # how many $Pn parameters were specified in the call to the function?
    $count = @( $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()
        | where-object { $_.Key.StartsWith("P") }
    ).Length;

    # if *none* specified then enable *all*
    $all = $count -eq 0;
    if( $all )
    {
        $P1 = $true;
        $P2 = $true;
    }

    "`$Name is $Name"
    "`$all is $all"
    "`$P1 is $P1"
    "`$P2 is $P2"

}
```

And some tests:

```
PS> Invoke-MyFunction
$Name is
$all is True
$P1 is True
$P2 is True

PS> Invoke-MyFunction -Name "aaa"
$Name is aaa
$all is True
$P1 is True
$P2 is True

PS> Invoke-MyFunction -Name "aaa" -P1
$Name is aaa
$all is False
$P1 is True
$P2 is False

PS> Invoke-MyFunction -Name "aaa" -P2
$Name is aaa
$all is False
$P1 is False
$P2 is True

PS>  Invoke-MyFunction -Name "aaa" -P1 -P2
$Name is aaa
$all is False
$P1 is True
$P2 is True
```

but watch out because the way I've evaluated `$count` means that specifying `-P1:$false` or `-P2:$false` makes `$all = $false`:

```
PS> Invoke-MyFunction -Name "aaa" -P1:$false
$Name is aaa
$all is False
$P1 is False
$P2 is False
```

so you might need to refine the expression to suit whatever you want to happen in this edge case...

---

**Update**

If your parameter names don't follow a simple pattern you can do something like this instead:

```
$names = @( "SomeParam", "AnotherParam", "Param3" );
$count = @( $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()
    | where-object { $_.Key -in $names }
).Length;
```

Comment: This is looking good.  I can definitely change the If block to collect the 15+ variables in the actual script if they all start with the same prefix:
```ForEach ($PVariable in (Get-Variable -Name "PVar*") {$PVariable = $true;}```

Comment: Okay, accepting this one as it led to my success and simplification of the original process.  Will post my final solution as an edit to my OP.  Thanks so much for the ideas!

Comment: @CitizenRon - added an update for checking if a set of arbitrary parameter names were specified in the function call...

Comment: I've been trying to figure out a way to implement your "$names" idea above but I didn't want to have to explicitly define the variable.  I wanted a way to do it programmatically for the script to find any number of parameter names that match.  I finally found it. ```($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Key -Like "Option*"}).Key ``` It still requires the Parameters to have a common prefix (or suffix) but I only have to define the parameters and the script does the organizing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are all switches and they belong to the parameter set of `'Individual'`, you can set the *unset* parameters to `$true` if `$All` is specified like so:

```
if ($All.IsPresent)
{
    (Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name).Parameters.Values | 
        Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.ParameterSets.Keys -eq 'Individual' } | 
        Foreach-Object -Process {
            Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $true -PassThru # remove -PassThru to silence the output
        }

}
```

Referencing the current executing command with `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`, you can pass it to `Get-Command` for more detailed info. on its parameters. This will allow you to filter by *ParameterSets* grabbing just the ones falling under `Individual`. Finally, it will pass it to `Set-Variable` setting all the switches to `$true` in a *dynamic* sense.